# crystal report OLE Object don't show in Browser

Tags: crystal-reports, report, image

I design a crystal report  and I insert a OLE Object as a picture(log image).

In my local PC，it works fine ,it shows the picture

but when i deploy it on iis ,it will not show picture in
browser.

Somebody can tell how to solve it? thanks

Comment: Is the image generated on the fly? Is it in your database? Is it the same for each report?

Comment: actually ,I am not clear  how to generate it.I just copy from one report

Comment: Is it a picture that's the same for each report, or is it a chart from data in the database?

Comment: yes,all report have the same picture.it is not from database.just a file.

Comment: Maybe you made a linked object instead of a static one? With OLE in crystal reports you can link (works like a hyperlink - you'd need the picture to be hosted on iis too, and if you linked and didn't host, then you'd get the problem you describe) or embed (like an equation in a Word document - comes with an editor), but I think you should try to have it static given it won't be changing.